# Any advantage of Bayesian methods for this data?

Tags: bayesian

I have data of blood sugar level and 8 predictor variables of 15000 subjects. Some of the predictor variables are categorical. I want to determine independent predictors of blood sugar levels. I can do this with linear multivariate analysis. Is there any advantage of using Bayesian methods for this kind of situation?

Comment: The same as always: More elegant interpretation, you can accounting for uncertainty taken for granted in frequentist models, and if you have it, you can incorporate prior information. It's not a data dependent issue.

Comment: OK. It will be great if you could explain in a full answer. I do not have any prior information.